# Handling of asynchronous NgRx actions

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have an Angular application, and the main view is split into 2 components. This will be regarding the handling of the dispatching of NgRx actions, in an asynchronous manner.

1) `MenuComponent` - this contains the various navigation buttons, such as the logout button. Upon clicking the logout button, it call `authenticationService.logout()`, which sends a http request to the backend, followed by logging out the user. Hence, this is an asynchronous operation.

```
public logout() {
  this.authenticationService.logout();
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
}
```

2) `DashboardComponent` - I have written the following to handle the `OnDestroy` lifecycle hook, which will be called whenever the component is destroyed. It uses NgRx for state management.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.store.dispatch(new UpdateDashboardConfiguration());
  this.store.dispatch(new ClearDashboardState());
}
```

Dispatching of the `UpdateDashboardConfiguration()` action will result in the application sending a http request to the server to save the dashboard's configurations, therefore it is asynchronous too.

The main question is, when the user decides to logout by clicking the logout button on the `MenuComponent`, is there a way to ensure that the dispatching of `UpdateDashboardConfiguration()` will be completed before the dispatching of `ClearDashboardState()` actions,  as well as `authenticationService.logout()` from the other MenuComponent are being called?

The preferred flow would be the following:

`UpdateDashboardConfiguration` => `ClearDashboardState` => `logout()`

For those who are wondering, `this.store.dispatch(new UpdateDashboardConfiguration()).subscribe(...)` will not work as store.dispatch() is of void type, and not an observable.

Thank you in advance.

---

For those who are interested, this is the `Effect` for the UpdateDashboardConfiguration action.

```
@Effect()
UpdateDashboardConfiguration$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<UpdateDashboardConfiguration>.(DashboardActionTypes.UpdateDashboardWidget),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectDashboardLayoutStateConfig)),
  switchMap(action => {
    return this.dashboardService.updateDashboardConfiguration(action).pipe(
      map(data => (new UpdateDashboardConfigurationSuccess(data))),
    );
  }
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'll need to modify what your logout function is doing. If you have a desired order for your actions to execute in, you shouldn't be letting them run asynchronously.

Since you're using NgRx you should be dispatching a `LogoutClicked` action rather than calling a service function. This will allow you to control the flow so you can handle everything in the correct order. You can set up an effect that handles `LogoutClicked` and dispatches the `UpdateDashboardConfiguration` action. Then when you handle `UpdateDashboardConfigurationSuccess` you can decide if you need to dispatch a `ClearDashboardState` action and from there you can finally dispatch a `Logout` action that calls your logout service function.

You'll probably need to update the payloads contained in your actions to help the effects make decisions about which actions to dispatch next. You can use the Content-Based Decider effect pattern found [here](https://blog.nrwl.io/ngrx-patterns-and-techniques-f46126e2b1e5).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not using NgRx for my MenuComponent, since I do not need to maintain any form of state for that. However, it is indeed a valid suggestion.